# Change table Information

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

Table 1: (Consumer)

```
UserName   | FirstName | LastName
'Magika12'   'Ronald'    'Ludwig'
```

Table 2: (ConsumerLocation)

```
UserName |  LocationID
'Magika12'  13234
```

Table 3: (Location)

```
LocationID | StreetNumber | StreetName |  Suburb | City |    Postalcode
13234        13             Baker Street  Melton   Brisbane  4242
```

And I would like to change the address of `Magika12` to this instead:

```
"124 Braelands Crescent, Albion, Melbourne, 9999"
```

Whereby the new table would look like:

```
LocationID | StreetNumber | StreetName |        Suburb | City |    Postal code
13234        124            Braelands Crescent  Albion   Melbourne 9999
```

I have tried something like this:

```
UPDATE 
    L1
SET 
    L1.StreetNumber = 124,
    L1.StreetName = 'Braelands Crescent',
    L1.Suburb = 'Albion' ,
    L1.City = 'Melbourne',
    L1.Postalcode = 9999
FROM Location L1
INNER JOIN ConsumerLocation
WHERE ConsumerLocation.UserName = 'Magika'
```

I know this is not correct, But I am not sure how to connect all the tables together to update the address of `Magika12`. I have made `UserName` the primary key of `Consumer`, and the primary foreign key of `ConsumerLocation`. And `LocationId` the primary key of `Location` and the primary foreign key of `Consumer Location`.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE 
    Location L1 
    JOIN ConsumerLocation CL ON CL.LocationID = L1.LocationID
SET 
    L1.StreetNumber = 124,
    L1.StreetName = 'Braelands Crescent',
    L1.Suburb = 'Albion' ,
    L1.City = 'Melbourne',
    L1.Postalcode = 9999
WHERE CL.UserName = 'Magika12';
```

In case you have multiple Location entries related to same username add to WHERE clause the LocationId:

```
WHERE CL.UserName = 'Magika12' AND CL.LocationID = 13234
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed condition of `join` statement. Should be like this:

```
UPDATE 
    Location L1
    INNER JOIN ConsumerLocation c on c.LocationID=L1.LocationID -- miseed on
SET 
    L1.StreetNumber = 124,
    L1.StreetName = 'Braelands Crescent',
    L1.Suburb = 'Albion' ,
    L1.City = 'Melbourne',
    L1.Postalcode = 9999
WHERE c.UserName = 'Magika'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your join needs an `ON` condition... try this.

```
 INNER JOIN ConsumerLocation ON Location.LocationId = ConsumerLocation.LocationId
```

When you `JOIN` without any `ON` condition you get all possible combinations of rows in the tables you join. That might be a lot of rows.